# SpriteKit default landscape orientation

Tags: swift, orientation, default, landscape

I am making a SpriteKit game that runs in both landscape modes. How can I pick the default landscape orientation?

When I first load the game it loads in landscapeLeft (home button is on left)

Looking at most games on the app store it seems the default orientation is the other way around (landscape right). I also prefer it to be that way.

I have tried playing around with the info.plist but couldnt find anything.

I dont see what i can change in my viewController either because I want to keep both landscape orientations.

```
 override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone {
        return .Landscape
    } else {
        return .Landscape
    }
}
```

Anyone know what I have to do?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change the order of items for Supported Interface Orientation key inside info.plist. The app will launch in whatever orientation is specified in the first item. By default, that would be landscape left. Just drag Item 1 (landscape right) in the place of Item 0 (landscape left):

[image: info.plist]

Comment: Duh. Thank you very much, I knew it was something there.

Answer (score 0):

You can set this in the View Controller by overriding:

```
override func preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation() -> UIInterfaceOrientation {
    return UIInterfaceOrientation.LandscapeLeft
}
```

Just return the orientation you want for the game View Controller.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This only allows 1 landscape orientation which is not what I am looking for.

Comment: then just return: `UIInterfaceOrientation.LandscapeRight` if that's the way you want it to be when it starts?

Comment: Hey, I still want my app to be able to run in both landscape orientations. I want to change the default orientation on app launch. Thanks again